# Delete Tree child node in Window application

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am working on a Windows application where I am showing logs using a treeview as shown below, here nodes are created dynamically on the basis of daily logs

**Logs -**

```
+ 12-02-2001
+ 12-02-2001
+ 12-02-2001
+ 12-02-2001
```

but I want to add delete button with each node as shown below

**Logs -**

```
+ 12-02-2001 Delete
+ 12-02-2001 Delete
+ 12-02-2001 Delete
+ 12-02-2001 Delete
```

Thanks.

Comment: OK, What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Shai, thanks for reply i didn't try any thing right now but i have no idea how i can add delete button with each node so that i can delete individual node.

Comment: Reniuz,it is Simple window application.

Comment: simple application made using winforms? You know that you can create windows app using wpf?

Comment: @Sunny, that doesn't answer the question. What UI framework are you using? Winforms, WPF, or something else?

Comment: @svick I am using Winforms there

Answer (score 1):

You can make it easier using ContextMenuStrip.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx

```
            //event handler for menuItem Click
    private void mnuDelNode_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        //better confirm before delete using a message box 

        DeleteRecursive(listView.SelectedNode);
    }
    private void DeleteRecursive(TreeNode root)
    {
        //your delete logic here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WindowsForms, you would need to implement [custom drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.aspx) of the TreeView and do hit testing on the Click event to see if the button was clicked.  The TreeView was not really designed to add in buttons, so you may wish to consider an alternative design, say adding in a right menu, a toolbar, and/or right click menu with the Delete command on it, as that would be significantly less work and more in line with how the standard Windows controls work (you don't see a bunch of buttons behind folder names in Windows Explorer's TreeView for instance).